# How do I create working tooltips in Angular2 with Angular techniques?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've searched a lot for an easy, simple, and most importantly Ng way to make tooltips, but I can't seem to find a uniform method for doing so. I've tried doing this using ngbToolTip following the documentation in ng-bootstrap, but it doesn't seem to work. Here is my HTML:

```
 <div class="checkboxes" *ngFor="let to of todo">
    <label id="checkbox-label">
        <!--<input *ngIf="to.importance != 'non'" type="checkbox" id="{{to.id}}checker"  name="ChecklistItem{{to.name}}" value={{to.name}}>-->
        <!--<span *ngIf="to.importance == 'non'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok completed-check" aria-hidden="true"></span>-->
        <div class="displayed-info">
            <div class="importance-change">
                <div id="red-block" (click)="changeToHigh(to.id)">
                </div>
                <div id="green-block" (click)="changeToMed(to.id)">
                </div>
                <div id="beige-block" (click)="changeToMeh(to.id)">
                </div>
            </div>
            <p *ngIf="to.importance == 'high'" class="todo-item highimportance">{{to.name}} should be done {{to.time}}</p>
            <p *ngIf="to.importance == 'medium'" class="todo-item mediumimportance">{{to.name}} should be done {{to.time}}</p>
            <p *ngIf="to.importance == 'meh'" class="todo-item mehimportance">{{to.name}} should be done {{to.time}}</p>
            <span *ngIf="to.importance == 'non'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok completed-check" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <div *ngIf="to.importance == 'non'" class="todo-item nonimportance">
                <p>{{to.name}} </p>
            </div>
            <span *ngIf="to.importance == 'non'" class="completed-task"> Completed!</span>
        </div>
    </label>
    <button class="btn btn-warning chkbx" (click)="onDelete(to.id)" ngbTooltip="tooltip">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
    <button *ngIf="to.importance != 'non'" class="btn btn-info chkbx" (click)="onCompleted(to.id)">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
    <button *ngIf="to.importance == 'non'" class="btn btn-info chkbx" disabled="true" (click)="onCompleted(to.id)">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

So I'm just adding one little tooltip on my delete button as a test, but it doesn't work.

Here is my app.module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {TodoService } from './todo.service';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [TodoService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My single component has the same import at the top of the .ts file too.

The html itself needs cleanup too I know, but I'm not there yet.

Any suggestions on how to setup tooltips, or anywhere there is documentation?

Comment: I would suggest you to use [**ngPrime**](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tooltip) tooltip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using SystemJS? Also remove  NgbModule.forRoot() from your component if you have. Post your component TS file.

You could also use  [Bootstrap 4 tooltip](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/) or [ngx-bootstrap tooltip](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tooltip)

Comment: Thank you both of these solutions worked. Guess I was using ng-bootstrap instead of ng2-bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

The code and demos at https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip work when I run them or when I incorporate similar code into other programs.  The only problem I've found is that the tooltips appear immediately, with no evident way of adding a delay.